# Override generic method with more narrow parametrization

Tags: java, generics

***What I have:***

I have a generic method which I want to override:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C {
  public <T extends A> void function(T param) { //will be overridden in heirs
    //...
  }
}
```

***What I want:***

There  will be few classes that extend C-class and narrow parametrization. Example:

```
class D extends C {
  @Override
  public <T extends B> void function(T param) { //T extends B, not A!! Or even better if it can be only B-class, not heirs
    //...
  }
}
```

***Question:***

*How can I achieve that?*

***EDIT:***

Class C has many heirs: D, F, G, H... Each of those classes has the single method `f(T param)`. And for each of those method I need `T` will be different heir of `Z` class in each case.

So I decide that I can set common API in C-class with help of generics. But if its impossible, maybe other way?

Comment: can't use parameterize the class itself?

Comment: If I understand you correct you are talking about parametrization of C and D classes. Am I right? Any way, don't grasp how it could help me.

Comment: exactly how sp00m put it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parameterizing your classes could be a solution:

```java
class C<T extends A> {

    public void function(T param) {
        // ...
    }

}

class D<T extends B> extends C<T> {

    @Override
    public void function(T param) {
        // ...
    }

}
```